# Terraform v0.14.3 failing on dynamic assignment of value for cidr_blocks

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure

I am trying to dynamically assign `cidr_blocks` to `ingress` state of `aws_security_group` as below :

```
resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls" {
  name        = "saurabh_security_group"


      ingress {
        description = "TLS from VPC"
        from_port   = 443
        to_port     = 443
        protocol    = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["${aws_eip.lb.public_ip}/32"]
      }
      tags = {
        Name = "allow_tls"
      }
    }
```

but it fails with below error :

```
Error: Invalid operand

  on reference.tf line 31, in resource "aws_security_group" "allow_tls":
  31:     cidr_blocks = [aws_eip.lb.public_ip/32]
    |----------------

    | aws_eip.lb.public_ip is "52.14.139.236"

Unsuitable value for left operand: a number is required.
```

Terraform version i am using is `0.14.3` . I also tried with just `cidr_blocks = ["aws_eip.lb.public_ip/32"]`, but failed as well . But that i can understand because since its a string involved here this will fail . But why above approach is not working i am not able to understand , as same works without any issues in v0.12 .

Comment: The error is when you had `[aws_eip.lb.public_ip/32]`, but in your question it is `["${aws_eip.lb.public_ip}/32"]`. These are two different code snippets. What was the actual error for the second case?